# How to use changed_when with ansible shell module?

Tags: ansible

I have a complex shell script that is run by ansible and I do want to communicate from it to ansible when changes were made on the system, so Ansible will know that the host was modified.

This is achieve by using `changed_when: condition` but the problem is that I cannot really rely on a specific exit code to be used for success_with_change instead of success_without_change.

What other options are available? Can I use `register:` and use the registered variable inside `changed_when:` in order to check for a placeholder string in the output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use registered variable. For example:

```
- shell: mycommand.sh
  register: script_res
  changed_when: "'changed' in script_res.stdout"
```

Comment: The [Error Handling In Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) section in the Ansible documentation has more examples like that. Also for other cases such as `failed_when`, and `fail: msg=...` `when:`, which is pretty handy a lot of times.